# Efficiency of Code for Matrix operations on Wave equation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I've written a wave superposition program that overlaps wave equations of multiple wave sources and then gives a single wave which contains all the constructive and destructive interferences and plots the intensities of superpositions. This code works but is very inefficient.

- If I give the points here as a 1000x1000 grid, the whole program takes a while to run.
- Is there any way I can make this code more efficient and clean using one or all of the following (Functions, lambda functions, mappable, defining 2D numpy arrays directly or similar?).
- If so, is there a way to measure the time it takes to run the operation. This isn't homework, am trying to build something on my own for my optics research. Thanks so much for your help in advance, I really appreciate it.

  ```
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   from sklearn import mixture
   import matplotlib as mpl
   from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
   from matplotlib import cm
   import scipy
   import scipy.ndimage
   import scipy.misc 

   xmin, xmax = 0,25
   ymin, ymax = -12.500,12.500
   xpoints, ypoints = 500,500
   points,amp,distance,wave=[],[],[],[]
   numsource=11

   x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xpoints)
   y=np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ypoints)
   xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y, sparse=False)
   pointer = np.concatenate([xx.reshape(-1,1),yy.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=-1)
   counter=len(pointer)
   A=[0]*counter #for storing amplitudes later

   # Arrays of point source locations
   source=tuple([0,(((numsource-1)/2)-i)*2.5] for i in range(0,numsource-1))

   # Arrays of Subtraction of Coordinates of Sources from Point sources (For Distance from source)   
   points=[(pointer-source[p]) for p in range(0,numsource-1)]

   # distance of each point in map from its source (Sqrt of Coordinate difference sum)
   distance=[(points[i][:,0]**2 + points[i][:,1]**2)**0.5 for i in range(0,numsource-1)]

   # Amplitudes of each wave defined arbitrarily
   amp= np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
   k=20

   # wave equation for each wave based on defined amplitude and distance from source
   wave=([amp[i] * np.sin (k*distance[i]) for i in range(0,numsource-1)])

   #superposition
   for i in range(0,numsource-1):
       A=A+wave[i]

   A=np.asarray(A)
   print(A)
   intensity = A**2

   #constructive, destructive superposition plot
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
   plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)
   plt.ylim(ymin,ymax)
   plt.scatter(pointer[:,0], pointer[:,1],c=intensity, cmap='viridis')
   plt.colorbar()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the computation time from 166 to 146 ms on my machine.

You want to get rid of the part where `A` is initialized as a 250,000x1 list then converted to an array. You can initialize it as an array directly. The parts I disabled are left as comments in your code.

```
#import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
#from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
#import scipy
#import scipy.ndimage
#import scipy.misc
#from sklearn import mixture
import time

class time_this_scope():
    "A handy context manager to measure timings."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.t0 = None
        self.dt = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.t0 = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.dt = time.perf_counter() - self.t0
        print(f"This scope took {int(self.dt*1000)} ms.")



def main():

    xmin, xmax = 0, 25
    ymin, ymax = -12.500, 12.500
    xpoints, ypoints = 500, 500
    points, amp, distance, wave = [], [], [], []
    numsource = 11

    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xpoints)
    y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ypoints)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=False)
    pointer = np.concatenate([xx.reshape(-1, 1), yy.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=-1)


#    counter = len(pointer)
#    A = [0]*counter #for storing amplitudes later
    A = np.zeros(len(pointer))

    # Arrays of point source locations
    source = tuple((0, (((numsource-1)/2)-i)*2.5) for i in range(0, numsource-1))

    # Arrays of Subtraction of Coordinates of Sources from Point sources (For Distance from source)
    points = [(pointer-source[i]) for i in range(0, numsource-1)]

    # distance of each point in map from its source (Sqrt of Coordinate difference sum)
    distance = [(points[i][:,0]**2 + points[i][:,1]**2)**0.5 for i in range(0, numsource-1)]

    # Amplitudes of each wave defined arbitrarily
#    amp = np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
    amp = np.array([4]*numsource)
    k = 20

    # wave equation for each wave based on defined amplitude and distance from source
    wave = [amp[i] * np.sin(k*distance[i]) for i in range(0, numsource-1)]

    #superposition
    for i in range(0, numsource-1):
        A = A + wave[i]
#        A = np.asarray(A)


    print(A)
    intensity = A**2

    #constructive, destructive superposition plot
#    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
#    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
#    plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
#    plt.scatter(pointer[:,0], pointer[:,1], c=intensity, cmap='viridis')
#    plt.colorbar()

# Timing.
total_time = 0
N = 20
for _ in range(N):
    with time_this_scope() as timer:
        main()
    total_time += timer.dt
print(total_time/N)
```

Now the plotting itself still takes 500 ms, so I think`imshow` would be a better option than `scatter`. I doubt matplotlib is very happy to have 250 000 markers to render.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! This is very helpful. 
More efficient for sure. I will now figure out how to change from scatter to imshow, I am not aware of that yet.